# What would you call this weird metallic apparatus that allows you to lift people?

Tags: word-request

[image]

The metallic bar that forms like a sort of inclined v, what would you call it. What's the most specific term you can find for it, and what's the most general term (name not related to its function if it's possible) you can find for it? I would like both, because this is a tricky object to describe.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It is called a **hoist** for which the [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/hoist) has this entry:

> **hoist**
>   NOUN
>
> **1.1** An apparatus for lifting or raising something.
>
> *I have four visits a day, two carers at a time, as the only way they can move me is by using a hoist.*

Comment: This hoist also has a trolley.

Answer (score 25):

This is a tool used by CNAs/nurses to lift patients. It's called a [patient lift](https://101mobility.com/products/for-home/patient-lifts/).

This specific one is a [ceiling lift](https://www.google.com/search?q=ceiling+lift&tbm=isch) made by [SureHands](https://www.surehands.com/products/ceiling-motor/) (aka "Handi-Move")

---

[Edit] After speaking to several CNA friends, another common name is ["hoyer"](http://www.hoyerlift.com/), which is a [genericized brand name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_trademark)

Answer (score 7):

Google Image Search says it's a "Handi-Move", which seems to be a manufacturer's brand name, that the thing made of metal tubes is a "body support", and that the motor thing is a ceiling hoist.

Answer (score 5):

We always referred to that as a [bariatric](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bariatric) lift.

Comment: Who is "we"?  Are you a member of the medical profession who has used this device in your work?  If so, please make that a part of your answer.

Comment: You don't have to be obese to need a mobility aid like this.

Answer (score 5):

I used to work in a hospital, and would call this a Hoyer lift. Though Hoyer is a brand and the design is somewhat different, I’d guess many nurses and nursing aides would take a look at this and call it a Hoyer lift.

Comment: I worked in a steel company. We called it an overhead crane.